# Не работает сортировка по StoredField в Lucene 8

Tags: java, lucene

При выполнении запроса с сортировкой в Lucene 8.4.1 получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'rating' (expected=NUMERIC).
```

Почему нельзя выполнить сортировку по StoredField?

В индекс добавляю документ так:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new StoredField("id", id));
document.add(new StoredField("rating", rating));
indexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

Выполняю поиск так:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory));
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("rating", SortField.Type.FLOAT, true));
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(queryBuilder.build(), 10, sort);
```

Comment: В чем проблема посмотреть на какой строке возникает `IllegalStateException` и убедиться, что ваши параметры метода соответствуют принимаемым типам конструктора?

Comment: Я смотрел, проблема в том, что Lucene не хочет выполнять сортировку по полю, которое имеет тип StoredField.
Приходится заводить еще одно дополнительное поле с типом FloatDocValuesField, чтобы проводить сортировку по нем.

Comment: Ну так на каком моменте исключение? Можете подсветить? У меня почти есть ответ.

Comment: Исключение выбрасывается здесь:
searcher.search(queryBuilder.build(), 10, sort);